# Community Wiki Usage

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki, deleted-answers

This is a response to the mod comments on [this now-deleted answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5448/621):

[image: Deleted Answer]

> @JAL That's not what Community Wiki is for. Although... perhaps asking Chenmunka to add the clarifying information to the existing answer would have been better.

I would argue the opposite.  According to [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/2415822) on Meta Stack Overflow, this is an acceptable use of Community Wiki:

> Post an answer with the solution in the comments, and make it Community Wiki by checking the Community Wiki box.

While I understand that Community Wiki answers are supposed to be collaboratively edited by the community, can I get a better understanding of why the mods don't think this is acceptable use of the Community Wiki?

Comment: I decided not to delete the answer made from my comment immediately as it may have been construed as deleting an answer to promote my own.  I planned to return to delete the answer, and my original comment, later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This was not a stance; merely a misremembering of what I assume<del>d</del> to be network-wide consensus. There was also some confusion as to where the comment originated from.

---

> Can I get a better understanding of why the mods don't think this is acceptable use of the Community Wiki?

`s/the mods/wizzwizz4/g`.

Just like real humans, I can't hold every piece of <del>legislation</del> community consensus in my head at once; this is why I posted two separate comments. One of them was an ordinary comment, and the other was explaining my mod action.

The comment about Community Wiki not being appropriate in this case was... dubious, to say the least. The strong insistence came from the mSE question [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227290/308065):

> There is nothing "wiki" or "community" about those posts, and that is because **in most cases CW is misused as a reputation denial mechanism. And while part of this misuse is by the communities,** a very large part is actually by SE itself.
>   (emphasis mine)

After some web searching, I found [the Meta MSE answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1560/316841) that I was thinking of when I wrote that comment:

> On the other hand, if one wants to add further information and not merely duplicate the content of someone else's comment, there is nothing wrong with **posting that as one's own (i.e. *not CW*) answer**.
>   (emphasis mine)

I'll re-emphasise that with what I *should* have been focussing on:

> On the other hand, **if one wants to add further information and *not merely duplicate* the content of someone else's comment,** there is nothing wrong with posting that as one's own (i.e. not CW) answer.
>   (emphasis mine)

You were completely right to call this out. :-)

---

**Edit:** Coming back to the question, I noticed that the comment in question was not, as I had decided after noticing that Chenmunka had posted an answer, posted on that answer; rather it was posted on the question shortly before Chenmunka answered. I should've checked this first; given this information I am not sure what I should have done. I doubt I would have taken action in this case.

Comment: Perhaps the definition of community wiki is usage is defined on the Main Meta, updated just last month:- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/236563